# PropertyPath to TransformGroup Children in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am animating two RenderTransforms of elements in a programmatic way in C# by doing the following:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shiftAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));
```

The problem is, now where I use two transforms, I needed to add a TransformGroup. But I cannot figure out how the path is accessed with it.

`TransformGroup.RenderTransform.X` or anything similar does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be:

```
new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].X");
```

and

```
new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleX");
```

Though this is kinda static with the hard coded index